# Symfony sessions in www.example.com and example.com

Tags: symfony

I am trying to make my users sessions to live for 1 year and to be valid in `www.example.com` and `example.com`, so far I have this in my `security.yml`:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        remember_me:
            key: %secret%
            lifetime: 31536000
            path: /
            domain: "*.example.com"
```

But still if I log in on `www.example.com`, and then later on `example.com` I observe I am not logged there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that specify domain: `"*.mydomain.com"` as a string is the proper way. One thing that I have in mind (without specific experience into this type of Symfony2 problematic) is to change value of `domain` in `.mydomain.com` (as is written here) or to "migrate this information" into `cookie_domain` as follow:

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_domain: .mydomain.com
```